# Reactjs: Unable to access props value in stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-props

I want to access the `props.auth` value from my stateless component.
But on trying to access it getting error of

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: [object Object]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Any suggestion here for this. Thank you.

//props value

[image]

//Stateless component

```
const LandingPage = (props) => {

    Navbar.propTypes = {
      auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      loading: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }


    const { isAuthenticated, user } = props.auth;
    
    return (
      <div className="container-big-content">

        { user ? (user.is_admin === true && isAuthenticated ? 
            ( <MenuLogin/> ) : ( <Route component={Error}/>) ):  <Route component={Error}/> }
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    loading: state.apiCallsInProgress > 0
  });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(LandingPage);
```

Comment: May you explain what you are trying to achieve in your return?

Comment: Hi @BensSteves . Thank you for your time. I just want to access isAuthenticated and user value for login purpose.

Comment: Are you sure the error is referring to this component? I don't see how this error can apply to the component shown.

Comment: Okay and if you logged isAuthenticated and user those look like your first screenshot?

Comment: @BensSteves yes. this is the data i get from {...props} .

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes I am getting here in this comeponent only. I am sure I am wrongly calling props value.

Comment: I'd wonder if MenuLogin or Error components aren't returning  a valid component or there's a mistake in exporting them?

Comment: @EvanMorrison thank you for your time. I used to call the same in class component. but here I am unable to get the value of isAuthenticated and user as well .

Comment: Your `MenuLogin` component's render method should have some error while trying to render multiple items. MenuItems?

Comment: Hell yaa. It seems some error from my end. As @EvanMorrison figure my error. I ahve removed `Error` component and tried. It seems it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobinZigmond suggested, it does not immediately look like the error is coming from this component.

We can clean up this component a little to help debugging.

```js
import MenuLogin from './path/to/MenuLogin'
import Error from './path/to/Error'
import Route from 'react-router'
const LandingPage = (props) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, user } = props.auth;
    
  const isUserAdmin = user && user.is_admin && isAuthenticated

  return (
    <div className="container-big-content">
      {isUserAdmin ? <MenuLogin /> : <Route component={Error} />}
    </div>
   );
}
  
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  loading: state.apiCallsInProgress > 0 
});

LandingPage.propTypes = { 
 auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
 loading: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LandingPage);
```